# Error connecting to local oracle database with cx_Oracle in Jupyter

Tags: python, oracle, jupyter, cx-oracle

I want to connect to local database with cx_Oracle but it throws an error:

`DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help`

I can connect to database with sqlplus and SQL Developer, but it doesnt work with Python cx_Oracle in Jupyter.

```
import cx_Oracle

host = 'localhost'
port = 1521
SID = 'xe'
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, SID)

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('user', 'passwd', dsn_tns)
```

Is it possible I messed sth. with environment variables or client installation?

```
echo ${ORACLE_HOME};
/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe

echo ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH};
/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib
```

I installed client in `/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib`

Answer (score 0):

- You may as well update cx_Oracle.  The DPI-1047 message is using text that was updated in recent versions.  This won't actually solve your problem
- Keep it clean.  Don't set ORACLE_HOME if you are using Oracle Instant Client.
- I suspect your environment variables aren't being propagated down to cx_Oracle.
- With a 64-bit XE, you shouldn't need to install Instant Client in your case (because your cx_Oracle message tells me it is 64-bit because the error is looking for a 64-bit Oracle client).  cx_Oracle can use the DB libraries.
- Once you sort out your library search path issue, you will then hit a problem with your connection string.  You are trying to use an old SID construct, but should use a [Service Name](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#oracle-net-connect-descriptor-strings). It needs to be set like:

```
    sn = 'xe'
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host, port, service_name=sn)
```

- The cx_Oracle documentation covers installation and also has a User Guide section that is worth reviewing https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: And you may want to get the newer Oracle XE 18c https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html  With this, your service name would be  `sn = 'xepdb1'`